# Installed apps are shown as Pending and are not accessible

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps

Yesterday my Lumia 640 (running Windows 10 Mobile 1703) restarted several times in the off-hours. I was thinking it just installs updates but as far as I can tell there were no updates installed.

But since that, a number of apps in the app list now have a subtitle that reads "Pending". Some of the apps came back to life when I clicked them, others just refuse to start. I have an SD card inserted and think this could be SD card related, or maybe not. I have set to install new apps to Phone (but some of the apps may have been installed before on the SD card). Who knows that behavior, what does it mean?

Comment: At some point, all apps were back to normal. So, I don't know what happened. Maybe this was a cloud restore after some failure/update.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar problem. If I remember right, I ended up uninstalling the app from settings (on my phone it's settings > Apps > Apps & features). After it was uninstalled, I re-installed it from the store.